# how to create instance with multiple Ephemeral Disks in Openstack client or openstacksdk

Tags: openstack, openstacksdk

This [website](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5384351) show nova tool could create instance with multiple ephemeral disks, but how could I achieve that through `openstack` command or **openstacksdk**?

And I could find any clue through the [`openstack flavor create -h`](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/rocky/user/flavors.html), it shows that only support one option **Ephemeral Disk GB**, and I can't figure out how to add multiple Ephemeral Disks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you already found the answer, this was added in python-openstackclient 5.5.0 References: [1](https://github.com/openstack/nova/commit/4da4b96296c6b6d4351ebd47e32d5049a88211f1),[2](https://review.opendev.org/c/openstack/python-openstackclient/+/771697),[3](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1877347)